# How do I make the name of my object dynamic

Tags: javascript, object

I will be creating new objects in my array and I want to be able to assign it with a dynamic name so that I can access it easier. 
The below is a sample of what I am looking to do. I want the value 'iWantThisDynamic' to be able to be a variable so that I can name it whatever i choose when I push it to my array.

I am using JavaScript. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
myArray = []; 
myArray.push({iWantThisDynamic:{'color' : 'red', 'image':'3.jpg'}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with arrays since array items are accessed by index, not by key. That's what objects are for.

```
myObj = {}; 
myObj.iWantThisDynamic = {'color' : 'red', 'image':'3.jpg'};
```

Or if the name is really dynamic:

```
var dynName = 'Dynamic';
myObj[dynName] = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I got it to work using your above sample as a reference. I ended up with:

var test = 'dynamic';
  myObj = {}; 
  myObj[test] = {'color' : 'red', 'image':'3.jpg'};

Answer (score 1):

You can give any object an `id` as a property. But it is not possible to have the `id` of the object (its name in your script) changed at runtime.

The runtime needs an identifier it can use to access your object (the memory address or reference to the memory) from the script.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response bash.d!